# Print function that consumes json.RawMessage directly

Tags: json, go

I'm doing some work with `Elasticsearch` and the query return a `Source` object which it's type is `*json.RawMessage`.

I only want to print it to screen without creating struct model for it and doing the obvious `json.Marshal`.

Is there a print function that will consume *json.RawMessage type and print it to screen?

Code sample:

```
 for _, hit := range serachResult.Hits.Hits {
    fmt.Println(hit.Source, "\n")
 }
```

This code run will result in un-readable array of bytes, apparently without the ability to just build a `string` from the raw message.

Comment: The first argument to `fmt.Printf` is always a format string. If you're not using one, use `fmt.Println`.

Comment: Yes you are right. I changed it and got un readable output (big list of numbers). So still not working.

Comment: Yes, it's a slice of bytes. Convert it to a string (or you could write it to os.Stdout yourself, possibly using fmt.Fprintf)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `%s` to printf:

```
for _, hit := range serachResult.Hits.Hits {
   fmt.Printf("%s\n", hit.Source)
}
```